# Why there is no function-try-block for lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer

```
void foo() try {} catch (...) {}
// OK, function-try-block
```

```
[]() try {} catch (...) {} ();
// error: expected ‘{’ before ‘try’
```

```
[]() { try {} catch (...) {} } ();
// OK, extra curly braces`
```

Why is the second variant not allowed?

Comment: Is version 1 really valid?

Comment: @JVApen Yes it is.

Comment: @JVApen It's intended to let you wrap a constructor in a try-catch block, which will then be able to catch any exceptions thrown during initialisation; since the object is already initialised by the time the constructor's body enters, special syntax is required to enter the try-catch block outside the body.  This allows the programmer to do any necessary cleanup for partially-constructed objects, before passing the exception along to be handled normally.  [Objects declared inside the function are considered to be in scope until the end of the catch block(s).]

Comment: Nice, I've learned something. I've also checked the [c++14 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf). 7.1.5 also prohibits it for constexpr. and 8.4.1 indeed allows this

Comment: @JVApen It can also be used for non-ctor functions, in which case it's equivalent to wrapping the function's body in a try-catch block, but with one less indentation level.  It can be useful for logging information about function state in debug builds, in a manner that can easily be disabled for normal builds and isn't as intrusive as putting the try-catch block inside the function body, but isn't as common because the syntax looks weird.

Comment: Would it wrap the lambda initialization in the try catch?  Probably not.

Comment: @JVApen: there are examples about that in doc [Exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/1354/exceptions#t=201608071947378083609)

Comment: Lambda is in, exceptions too, though I doubt this is in.

Comment: @JustinTime a function-try-block also has another characteristic - any exception caught is automatically rethrown when the `catch` exits, the exception cannot be swallowed. Unlike a `try-catch` inside the function body, which can.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Only for constructors and destructors.

Comment: well.. don't use anything but third one.. seriously..

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nope. ["The currently handled exception is rethrown if control reaches the end of a *handler* of the *function-try-block* of a **constructor or destructor**. Otherwise, flowing off the end of the *compound-statement* of a *handler* of a *function-try-block* is equivalent to flowing off the end of the *compound-statement* of that function (see \[stmt.return\])."](http://eel.is/c++draft/except#handle-14)

Comment: Seems like a vanilla question of scope, but I could be wrong. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Originally, function-try-blocks were introduced to be able to catch exceptions thrown in constructors or destructors of subobjects. The syntax was extended to normal functions for consistency.

It would, of course, be possible to introduce such syntax for lambdas. However, as opposed to constructors and destructors, there is no practical advantage over simply enclosing the try-block in another pair of `{ }`, except the latter looks much less obscure.

Comment: One possible advantage is stuff like this:
`const auto x = ([] try {...} catch {...}) ();`
to be able to write catch blocks in the outer scope.

Comment: I upvoted that comment, but then I realized it made no sense.